# Obtaining data in a request in rust

Tags: web-scraping, rust, rust-tokio, reqwest

When I request data off a website https://unqnft.io/#/market or https://unqnft.io/#/trades, in the text there is a ton of content missing. The page seems to be fetching the data from elsewhere.

```
use scraper::{Html, Selector};
error_chain! {
      foreign_links {
          ReqError(reqwest::Error);
          IoError(std::io::Error);
      }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {

    println!("Start of the file: ");
    let res = reqwest::get("https://unqnft.io/#/market")
    .await?
    .text()
    .await?;

    println!("Length of stories {:?} ", res);
    let fragment = Html::parse_document(&res);

    // Additionally, how would i select something that has a tag of #anch_10? 
    let stories = Selector::parse("#anch_10").unwrap();
    println!(" ");
    println!(" ");
    println!(" ");

    for story in fragment.select(&stories) {
         let story_txt = story.text().collect::<Vec<_>>();
         println!("{:?}", story_txt);
     }
```

This returns This:

```
"<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"><meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#000000\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\"><link rel=\"manifest\" href=\"manifest.json\"><title>Unique Network NFT Marketplace</title><link rel=\"preconnect\" href=\"https://fonts.gstatic.com\"><link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap\" rel=\"stylesheet\"><link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap\" rel=\"stylesheet\"><link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap\" rel=\"stylesheet\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"theme.css\"><link href=\"react.01.95688c15.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"><link href=\"main.2c2dad92.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><script>var link = document.querySelector(\"link[rel~='icon']\");\n      if (!link) {\n        link = document.createElement('link');\n        link.rel = 'icon';\n        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);\n      }\n      link.href = 'favicon.ico';</script><script src=\"./env.js\"></script><div id=\"root\"></div><div id=\"tooltips\"></div><script>if (window.self !== window.top) {\n        window.top.location.href = window.location.href;\n      }</script><script src=\"other.00.43aa4f28.js\"></script><script src=\"robohash.02.16a88645.js\"></script><script src=\"polkadot.01.21109aeb.js\"></script><script src=\"robohash.00.3a841187.js\"></script><script src=\"polkadot.02.e99664ce.js\"></script><script src=\"react.01.69a27675.js\"></script><script src=\"robohash.01.dbfaecb9.js\"></script><script src=\"other.02.a8d8c091.js\"></script><script src=\"polkadot.00.31bbf1a4.js\"></script><script src=\"react.00.cb68007d.js\"></script><script src=\"other.01.733fa76f.js\"></script><script src=\"main.5af7eb1e.js\"></script></body></html>"
```

and inspecting the elements i can trace it to somewhere in 'App-container'. How do i acceess that? They seem to be behind theese "Robotshash" Scripts that i don't see.

```
<script src=\"other.00.43aa4f28.js\"></script><script src=\"robohash.02.16a88645.js\"></script><script src=\"polkadot.01.21109aeb.js\"></script><script src=\"robohash.00.3a841187.js\"></script><script src=\"polkadot.02.e99664ce.js\"></script><script src=\"react.01.69a27675.js\"></script><script src=\"robohash.01.dbfaecb9.js\"></script><script src=\"other.02.a8d8c091.js\"></script><script src=\"polkadot.00.31bbf1a4.js\"></script><script src=\"react.00.cb68007d.js\"></script><script src=\"other.01.733fa76f.js\"></script><script src=\"main.5af7eb1e.js\"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: The elements are probably generated by js. Try "View source" (Ctrl+U in Chrome) and not "Inspect elements".

Comment: Even better, use the network debug pane and look for XHRs. The data is probably being fetched from an API, which would be immediately visible there.